# Foreach Ajax para combo

Tags: php, ajax

Tenho o seguinte trecho Ajax para alimentar input do tipo text ou select com valores já definidos:

```
                ids.forEach(function (id) {
                    document.getElementById(id).value = dados[id];
                });
```

Gostaria de saber se tem como criar uma option nova para um campo do tipo select que eu definir, usado o resultado do Ajax. Por exemplo: No HTML tenho declarado o select sem nenhum option, ele só seria criado a partir do resultado desse Ajax. É possivel?

Comment: Sim, usa o ForEach ou Each em conjunto com o Append.

Comment: Poderia me dar um exemplo de como usar append?

Comment: Pronto, retirada citação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O retorno deve ser em **json**.

```
return json_encode($cidades)
```

### JS

```
   var box_select = $('#cidades');
   var estado = $(this).val();

   $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: urlBase + '/busca-cidades',
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        data: { estado: estado },
        success: function(data){
            if(estado != ''){
                box_select.html('');

                // Faz o ForEach
                $.each(data, function(i, val){
                    // Append tem a função de inserir
                    box_select.append("<option value='"+val.id+"'>"+val.nome+"</option>");
                });
            }
            else{
                box_select.html('');
            }
        }
    });
```

Para chamar esse AJAX faça uma função `onchange` no combobox.

Comment: Eu não entendi porque do async false e cache false, xmlhttprequest síncrono está em desuso, e método POST não gera cache.

Comment: Editei a pergunta com a tua idéia @Zoom.

Comment: @Zoom, resolvi o problema, muito obrigado. Vou editar a pergunta com a resposta.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento chora muito

Comment: Alem desse loop com o metodo each do jquery você tambem pode usar o for do proprio JS:
for(var i in data){
 box_select.append("<option value='"+data[i].id+"'>"+data[i].nome+"</option>");
}

Comment: @Zoom o que quer dizer com isto? Poderia ser mais claro, estou apenas tentando lhe dar uma crítica construtiva